# Ошибка в алгоритме сортировки структур

Tags: c

Задача - получить данные в формате - Название журнала Индекс Покупатель.
Отсортировать в таком формате - Индекс Назавание К-во покупателей.
Найти 2 журнала с найбольшым к-вом покупателей.

```
struct edition{      //храним введенные данные 
    char name[50];   //название ж
    int index;       //индекс
    char subscr[50]; //Покупатель
};
struct result{       //отсортированые данные
    int index;       //индекс
    char name[60];   //название ж
    int count;       // К-во покупателей
};

int main()
    {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

     int num,  //к-во введенных значений
         i,j,  //счетчики
         flag, //прапор, если елемента еще нет в структуре результатов
         pos;  //значение последнего индекса в массиве структур результата

    printf("Какое к-во записей ?\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    struct edition data[num];

    printf("\nВведите: Название журнала Индекс Покупатель\n");
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        printf("%d. ",i+1);
        scanf("%s %d %s",data[i].name,&data[i].index,data[i].subscr); // запись в структуру
    }

    struct result res[num]; // инициализация структуры результата

    strcpy(res[0].name , data[0].name); // заносим 0 элемент в новий массив
    res[0].index = data[0].index;
    res[0].count = 1;

    pos = 0; //для того чтобы не было "пустых" элементов в массиве структур результата
    for(i=1;i<num;i++){
        flag = 0; // записать элемент или нет
        for(j=0 ;j<sizeof(res)/sizeof(struct result);j++){
            if( data[i].index == res[j].index ){ // если элемент уже записан
                res[j].count++;// инкрементируем к-во
                break; // next элемент
            }else{
                flag = 1; // записать элемент
                pos++;// ичейка массива
            }
        }
        if( flag == 1 ){ // запись элемента в массив результатов
            strcpy(res[pos].name , data[i].name);
            res[pos].index = data[i].index;
            res[pos].count = 1;
        }
    }


    printf("%5s  %12s  %20s\n","Индекс","Назавание ","К-во покупателей\n");

    for(i=0;i<sizeof(res)/sizeof(struct result);i++){ //выводим результат
        printf("%5d  %12s  %5d\n", res[i].index, res[i].name, res[i].count);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Но где-то в алгоритме ошибка, поскольку подсчет неверный и при выводе результатов выводит неверный результат и абракадабру.

Comment: Трассировка, трассировка и ещёраз трассировка. С левой стороны ставите watch или контрольные значения так что б было видно все елементы массива - с правой код, или наоборот. И трассируете.

Comment: На счёт `scanf("%s %d %s"` - пой опыт показывает, что так лучше не рисковать. проверяйте начиная с scanf. Если это не студенческая задача - используйте sort ф-цию

Comment: увы, нужно самому понять как нужно сортировать.

Answer (score 1):

Надо внести пару правок в код, и он заработает: инкрементировать `pos` непосредственно перед записью нового элемента и печатать не весь массив результатов, а только фактически используемую часть:

```
for(i=1;i<num;i++){
    flag = 0; // записать элемент или нет
    for(j=0 ;j<sizeof(res)/sizeof(struct result);j++){
        if( data[i].index == res[j].index ){ // если элемент уже записан
            res[j].count++;// инкрементируем к-во
            break; // next элемент
        }else{
            flag = 1; // записать элемент
        }
    }
    if( flag == 1 ){ // запись элемента в массив результатов
        ++pos;// ичейка массива
        strcpy(res[pos].name , data[i].name);
        res[pos].index = data[i].index;
        res[pos].count = 1;
    }
}


printf("%5s  %12s  %20s\n","Индекс","Назавание ","К-во покупателей\n");

for(i=0;i<=pos;i++){ //выводим результат
    printf("%5d  %12s  %5d\n", res[i].index, res[i].name, res[i].count);
}
```

Comment: Если бы все переменные имели внятные имена, а условия были бы сохранены во временных переменных (тоже с понятными именами), то ошибки в логике программы всплыли бы сразу...